# Install Facebook plugin using Cordova CLI 5.1.1

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, cordova-5.0.0

I am developing app in cordova with CLI version 5.1.1. Everything works fine (App gets successfully build) until I use facebook connect plugin in cordova - [Facebook cordova plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md).

Error I get:

```
P-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:dexDebug

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/acce
ssibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionI
mpl;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:45
4)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:dexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        C:\Users\INTEL\android-sdks\build-tools\22.0.0\dx.bat --dex --no-optimiz
e --output C:\MyApps\Impulse\platforms\android\build\intermediates\dex\debug --in
put-list=C:\MyApps\Impulse\platforms\android\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\in
putList.txt
Error Code:
        2
Output:

        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
        com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support
/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfo
VersionImpl;
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.ja
va:596)
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:
554)
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:
535)
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)

                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main
.java:454)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
                at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.823 secs

C:\MyApps\Impulse\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\MyApps\Impulse\platforms\andro
id\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\MyApps\Impulse\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dor
g.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
rdova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)
```

I think this is because gradle build used in cordova version 5.0 and above and facebook uses ant build.

How can I install this plugin correctly for gradle build?

Comment: I encountered a similar issue because the plugin refrences an android lib in one version while I had the ionic push plugin referencing a different version of the same jar. Are you using ionic push plugin? If not, check for other plugin that use that jar.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: Remove Android v4 jar file and plugin will work like charm. Jar files are getting clashed in CLI 5.1 Jar file location: `App\platforms\android\libs`